# How to model two representations of a single entity (skip legacy fields in it)?

Tags: java, mysql, scala, dao

This is a design decision which I'm trying to learn best practices.

I have a legacy code which it has a `Model` object and related `Dao` object for db layer interactions.
Model data is actually stored in three different table. Model is missing some columns from these tables that actually doesn't needed for the current system.

Now I have another requirement for this missing columns and I need a full version of this model for new modules (for web client).

One solution is updating the `Model` object and updating the queries in `Dao` so each of the modules can use same code base. 
But then legacy code will have redundant fields never used. It'll broke the encapsulation.

Another solution is creating different versions of `Model` and `Dao` but then there would be code duplication and maintenance complexity at some point.

How to proceed?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you subclass Model and Dao to extend them with the functionality to support the new columns?

Comment: I simplified the case but model has inner arrays of another models which they also have changing fields. Extending dao means overriding all queries and also changing anorm parsers which match db results with models. So it's near to duplicating code so I guess inheritance is not helping as much.  I kinda feel having two versions is right because they're serving for different business part so they should have different. But then engineer inside me, warn me something should be better :)

Comment: I hear you :-) If this legacy is going to phased out soon, maybe you could live with exposing the extra fields. If the legacy won't change any time soon, deprecating the current Model/Dao (and don't change it anymore), and promoting a copy as the new standard seems sensible. Otherwise, I'm afraid you're going to have to refactor the code to minimize maintenance. Maybe it's a good time to start fresh with a new implementation for this part only, and deprecate all the legacy.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "redundant fields never used". They appear to be used by the newer model? If you don't want your legacy client to use those fields, then you could use a trait. Maybe adding some code snippets would help.

Comment: Yes trait would make sense, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

I think there can be several solutions:

- Refactor fields you don't need every time into separate models / tables and load them as needed as a 1:1 relation.
- Use inheritance to make two models and two dao objects (repositories?) and use factories to instantiate them when needed.

> Extending dao means overriding all queries and also changing anorm
>   parsers which match db results with models.

You just need to address fields by name, not by column number and provide different repositories different set of fields to fetch. It should be easy to construct SELECT queries, that differ only in set of fields.

Comment: I think I can refactor the dao as you said, but can't separate into another table, it will broke the logical integrity of data.

Comment: @FatihDonmez I see. Refactoring database is always hard. Well, try to. If you will have problems, post them as a question and drag me to it ;)